# Magento 2 get Stock Item of virtual Product

Tags: magento2, out-of-stock, get, virtual

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): The stock item with the "2056" ID wasn't found. Verify the ID and try again.

```
-----In block File--------------
public function getLoadProduct()
{
    $product_id = $this->getCurrentProduct()->getId();
    return $this->productloader->create()->load($product_id);
}
 public function getStockItem($productId)
{
    return $this->stockItemRepository->get($productId);
}

         ------phtml file-------------
          $productLoad = $block->getLoadProduct();
          $productStockData = $block->getStockItem($productLoad->getId());
          echo $productStockData->getQty();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;

class MyCustomClass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_stockItemRepository;
        
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class ProductGetItem extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_stockItemInterface;
        
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $_stockItemInterface,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_stockItemInterface = $_stockItemInterface;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    
    public function getStockItem($product)
    {
        if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
            $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
            $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);
            $count = 0; 
            foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) { 
                $productQty = $this->_stockItemInterface->getStockItem($child->getId());
                round($count+=$productQty->getData('qty'));
            } 
            return $count;
        } else {
            $productQty = $this->_stockItemInterface->getStockItem($product->getId());
            return round($productQty->getData('qty'));
        }
        
    }
    public function getStockItemById($productId)
    {
        $productQty = $this->_stockItemInterface->getStockItem($productId);
        return round($productQty->getData('qty')); 
    }
}
```

or objectManager

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
$productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
$productStockObj = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
    $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);
    $count = 0; 
    foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) { 
        $productQty = $productStockObj->getStockItem($child->getId());
        round($count+=$productQty->getData('qty'));
    } 
    echo $count;
} else {
    $productQty = $productStockObj->getStockItem($product->getId());
    echo round($productQty->getData('qty'));
}
```